# How to put a label under each column in a SSRS chart

Tags: reporting-services

I have made a chart in SSRS but cannot figure out a way to get the x-axis to show a number under each column(Month).

Does any one have any advice?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ah I got it, I needed to set the interval in the chart-axis to 1